# regarding extracting the segmented result

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have an image, and perform `K-means`-based segmentation against is using `slic` method. The code and result are attached. My question is that How can I extract the information for each segmented patch, such as its location, area, label, or related pixel values, etc.

```
segments = slic(img, n_segments = 250, sigma = 5,compactness=0.1)
```

[image]
[image]

As advised, I used `props = regionprops(segments)` to extract the segmented patches. It turns out that props only has 249 elements instead of 250 as I setup in `slic` method. what causes the mismatch here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops). Note: SLIC currently returns values in `[0, ..., n_labels-1]`, but `regionprops` ignores 0, so you should add 1 to the output of SLIC.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your answer, i have updated my original post. The result of regionprops only gives 249 elements instead of 250 as I expected. is this what you were referring to in your answer. Please clarify. Thank you. Moreover, if I want to get the average pixel value of each segmented patch, should I use mean_intensity in the output? Thanks.

Comment: you should use `segments = slic(...) + 1`, then `regionprops(segments, intensity_image=img)` yes, use `regionprops[i].mean_intensity` for each i, as well as any other properties you are interested in.

Comment: Hi Juan, Thanks!